# Set value to dropdown after call method change() not working

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, onchange

**Description**: When select a option from **alcanceMarca**, populate **alcanceProducto** based on a value from alcanceMarca and after this I need to set (select) value to alcanceProducto.

**Problem**: The problem is that no set (select) value of alcanceProducto because when set the value, the method change(). is not finished.

And I **guess** that I need to find the way to set value of alcanceProducto just after finished change().

**My code**

```
enlace = 5; //for example
idMps = 3;

$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceMarca').find('select').val(enlace).change();
console.log($('#editMPS_structure .alcanceProducto').find('select').find('option'));
$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceProducto').find('select').val(idMps);

$('.marca').on('change', function() {
    //Populate select select.marca from database using jquery ajax, this part works perfectly   
})
```

**$('#editMPS_structure .alcanceMarca').find('select')** is equal to **.marca**

For example:

I have this default select:

```
<select class="marca">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
</select>

<select class="producto">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
</select>
```

After populate **producto**  based on option 1 in **.marca**

```
<select class="marca">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="1">Option1</option>
</select>

<select class="producto">
    <option value="0">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="1">OptionProd1</option>
    <option value="2">OptionProd2</option>
    <option value="3">OptionProd3</option>
</select>
```

And I need to set value = 3, but not working because the dropdown .alcanceProducto still not pupulate.

I realized that is not loaded because what is display on the console between the method call change() and set value, only appears the option 0, and do not show the 3 options you should have uploaded.

Comment: do you mind trying [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are populating the options from an ajax request.

You need to set the value inside the success callback of `ajax` request so the the options are available at the time you set the value.

```
$('.marca').on('change', function() {
      $.ajax({
           ....
           ....
           success : function(data) {

               // Populate the options

              // Then set the value here
              $('.producto').val(3);
           }
      });
})
```

Comment: I thought there was some other function or method with jQuery, but this way has worked, thanks.

Comment: Glad to have helped :)